# Remove an empty string from sub lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, duplicates

I have a list of lists, with strings and empty strings in it.

My goal is to stay with the same structure and data (list of lists), but remove the empty strings.

```
my_list = [["Tom", "Boy", ''], ["Ben", "Ten", '']]
```

I tried this but it returns an error:

```
        for lists in new_list:
            for word in lists:
                if word == "":
                    new_list.remove(word)
        return new_list
```

If it matters, the empty strings in the sub lists is always in the last index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use nested *list comprehension* with conditional check for empty string as:

```
my_list = [["Tom", "Boy", ""],["Ben", "Ten", ""]]

new_list = [[s for s in sub_list if s] for sub_list in my_list]
# where `new_list` will hold:
#   [['Tom', 'Boy'], ['Ben', 'Ten']]
```

---

However, as you mentioned that your empty string is always the last element in the nested list. You can use the  `del` command to delete the last element as:

```
my_list = [["Tom", "Boy", ""],["Ben", "Ten", ""]]
for sub_list in my_list:
    del sub_list[-1]

# New value of `my_list` will be:
#   [['Tom', 'Boy'], ['Ben', 'Ten']]
```

Or, the *list comprehension* way to skip the last element in sub-list:

```
new_list = [sub_list[:-1] for sub_list in my_list]
```

Comment: Good answer, I like the final version best.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what it looks like with a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [["Tom", "Boy" ''],["Ben", "Ten", '']]

new_list = [[s for s in l if len(s)>0] for l in my_list]

print(new_list)
```

**Output**

```
[['Tom', 'Boy'], ['Ben', 'Ten']]
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```py
x = [["dhasdjs","dsd"],["","sdds"]]
for lists in x:
    for item in lists:
        if item == "":
            lists.remove(item)
print(x)
```

Comment: never remove items from a list you are iterating over.